# How can I prepare a TortoiseSVN installer to use the serf HTTP library instead of neon?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoise-svn

I'm going to be distributing instructions on how to access our new Subversion repository with TortoiseSVN. Because it's hosted on Windows, and we have some large files in the repository, we have to use the [Serf HTTP library](https://code.google.com/p/serf/) instead of [neon](http://www.webdav.org/neon/).

This is normally specified by manually editing the Subversion "servers" file on the client machine and adding the line

```
http-library=serf
```

Is there a way I can customize the TortoiseSVN installer to do this automatically? I'm just trying to get it up and running as easy as possible for our new SVN users.